# Java - Retrieve values from List

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist

I added 3 strings into a List (Should I call this ArrayList ?)
And don't know how to retrieve.

```
      String f1;
      String f2;
      String f3;
      f1="1";
      f2="2";
      f3="3";
      List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
      String[] e = new String[] {f1,f2,f3};
       list.add(e);
       System.out.println(list.get(0,1));
      for (int inT=0;inT<=list.size();inT++)
      {
          System.out.println(list.get(inT));
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to add some items and retrive them you dont need a separate arrays to be stored in the ArrayList. List means List of arrays and not List of Strings.

You should be doing this,

```
String f1;
String f2;
String f3;
f1 = "1";
f2 = "2";
f3 = "3";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(f1);
list.add(f2);
list.add(f3);

for (String listItem : list) {
    System.out.println(listItem);
}
```

Comment: I think this is not OP wants, he want to store the values in the form of `String []` and retrieve the values of that list. Please refer my answer for the further solution.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani from the snippet in the query you can understand that hes just learning and not aware of how to add/retrieve data from Array list. My snippet explains the simple way to do it. Not to complicate his already complicated code.